# How do I set the elementFormDefault of an Element in JAXB on a single class basis instead of having it set for the entire package?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, schema

I know I could use @XmlSchema to do this but the problem is we have a class in the same package that needs its namespace to be different from what's defined on package-info.java. So we declared the namespace in @XmlRootElement instead (of course while still having @XmlSchema in place). But doing this will not allow us to set the class's elementFormDefault. Moving the class to a different package is not an option. Basically, I just want to override the namespace for this particular class.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

When `elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` is set on `@XmlSchema`, you can override then namespace for the properties of a class by annotating it with `@XmlType(namespace="ANOTHER_NAMESPACE")`.  If you want to override the namespace for a root element you can do `@XmlRootElement(namespace="DIFFERENT_NAMESPACE)`.

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

---

**JAVA MODEL**

***Bar***

You just need to set the namespace on the `@XmlType` annotation for the `Bar` class.

```
package forum14579814;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(namespace="FOO")
public class Bar {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

***package-info***

This will override the namespace that you specified in package level `@XmlSchema` annotation.

```
@XmlSchema(namespace="FOO2", elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package forum14579814;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

***Foo***

This object is the root of your domain model.

```
package forum14579814;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**XML SCHEMAS**

Below are the XML schemas that you provided via http://jsfiddle.net/supertonsky/Phck5/.

***Foo.xsd***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="FOO2"
    xmlns:tns="FOO2" 
    xmlns:tns2="FOO"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <import namespace="FOO" schemaLocation="BAR.xsd"></import>
    <element name="foo" type="tns:Foo"></element>
    <complexType name="Foo">
        <sequence>
            <element name="bar" type="tns2:Bar"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

***Bar.xsd***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="FOO"
    xmlns:tns="FOO" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <complexType name="Bar">
        <sequence>
            <element name="name" type="string" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

**DEMO CODE**

The following demo code will create an instance of the domain object and output it to XML.  The XML output will be validated during the marshal operation against the XML schemas that you provided.

```
package forum14579814;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.validation.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setName("BAR");

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar(bar);

        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("src/forum14579814/Foo.xsd"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setSchema(schema);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Then you would get the following output.  Note how the `name` element that corresponds to the `name` property on `Bar` is qualified with the `FOO` namespace while all the other elements are qualified with the `FOO2` namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:foo xmlns="FOO" xmlns:ns2="FOO2">
    <ns2:bar>
        <name>BAR</name>
    </ns2:bar>
</ns2:foo>
```

Comment: You almost hit it. Pardon me if I sometimes suck at asking the right question. Actually my problem is, as in your example, I want the class Bar to remain `QUALIFIED` (as instructed in the `package-info.java`) even if I set its namespace through `@XmlType` or `@XmlRootElement`. By looking at the given XML, the class `Bar` seems to be in `UNQUALIFIED` form even if the `package-info.java` set it to `QUALIFIED` (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @supertonsky - `Bar` is namespace qualified.  In that example doc it just happens to correspond to the default namespace.

Comment: I tried changing the `Foo`'s namespace to `FOO2` using @XmlRootElement  and removed namespace declaration from Bar. What happened was Foo became unqualified. I'm getting `<ns2:foo xmlns:ns2="FOO2" xmlns="FOO"><bar><name>BAR</name></bar></ns2:foo>` which is no longer in qualified form. So when I validate it against schema which is qualified, it fails.

Comment: @supertonsky - `Foo` is still qualified.  The `foo` element is qualified with the namespace `FOO2` and the elements `bar` and `name` are qualified with the `FOO` namespace.  Elements with out a prefix correspond to the default namespace (`xmlns=`FOO"`).

Comment: Thanks Blaise, but I do really believe it's unqualified. I have created the schema for this and the generated XML fails validation against the schema. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/supertonsky/Phck5/

Comment: @supertonsky - Thank you for providing the schemas.  The Foo.xml file you provide is not valid against the schemas you provided.  I have updated my answer (including a validation) step to show that the mappings are correct.

Comment: Sorry for this hassle Blaise, I should have made the question in detailed form. I was simply trying to make the question short. Apparently it works only for `Bar`. Now from your example, try removing the Bar's `@XmlRootElement` `namespace` attribute and set the Foo's `@XmlRootElement` `namespace` to `FOO2` and `@XmlSchema`'s `namespace` to FOO. That will reproduce the problem. What I wanted was I must be able to change `Foo`'s `namespace` that's different from what's declared in `@XmlSchema` while remaining in qualified form as declared in `@XmlSchema`.

Comment: I have updated the link (http://jsfiddle.net/supertonsky/Phck5/) to reflect the changes I want in the code.

Comment: If I change the `namespace` on `@XmlSchema` to `FOO`, and remove the `namespace` from the `@XmlType` annotation on `Bar`. Then I need to annotate `Foo` with both `@XmlRootElement(namespace="FOO2")` and `@XmlType(namespace="FOO2")`.

Comment: But that's the problem, I wan't to be able to change the namespace of the class `Foo` to something different from the package while remaining in qualified form as declared in the package.

Comment: @supertonsky - That is done with the `@XmlType` annotation.  Here is another example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651918/unmarshalling-with-multiple-namespaces/14652368#14652368

Comment: I updated the link (http://jsfiddle.net/supertonsky/Phck5/) to include the `@XmlType`. I can't remove `@XmlRootElement` from `Foo`. Now I'm getting  the following error `Cannot resolve the name 'tns2:Bar' to a(n) 'type definition' component.` I included the generated XML output on the link. I have no problem marshalling it, but unmarshalling it back from XML against schema is not working.