# Unmarshalling with multiple namespaces

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey

So, lets say I have this xml with several namespaces.

```
<Envelope xmlns:pdi="http://www.mypage.com/schemas/pdi" xmlns:ib="http://www.mypage.com/schemas/ib" xmlns="http://www.mypage.com/schemas/envelope">
  <Product>
    <pdi:number>123456</pdi:number>
  </Product>
  <Instance>
    <ib:serial>abcdefg</ib:serial>
  </Instance>
</Envelope>
```

I'm trying to build a client for it. I have an Envelope POJO that's declared like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name ="Envelope", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/envelope")
public class Envelope
```

and inside, it has these attributes

```
@XmlElement(name="Product", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/pdi")
public Product getProduct(){...}

@XmlElement(name="Instance", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/ib")
public Instance getInstance(){...}
```

Also, the Product POJO looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Product", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/pdi")
public class Product
```

and attribute

```
@XmlElement(name="pdi:number", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/pdi")
public int getNumber(){...}
```

For some reason, I can't get the product number. I keep getting a request error. Am I handling the namespaces correctly, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this use case I would recommend leveraging the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the namespace qualification.

**package-info (forum14651918/package-info.java)**

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace="http://www.mypage.com/schemas/envelope", 
    elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
    xmlns={
            @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/envelope", prefix = ""),
            @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/ib", prefix = "ib"),
            @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/pdi", prefix = "pdi")
    }
)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
package forum14651918;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

**Envelope (forum14651918/Envelope.java)**

Since we have specified a `namespace` and `elementFormDefault` on the `@XmlSchema` annotation, all the elements corresponding to the `Envelope` class will be automatically qualified with the `http://www.mypage.com/schemas/envelope` namespace.

```
package forum14651918;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="Envelope")
public class Envelope {

    @XmlElement(name="Product")
    private Product product;

    @XmlElement(name="Instance")
    private Instance instance;

}
```

**Product (forum14651918/Product.java)**

You can override the namespace for the `Product` class using the `@XmlType` annotation.

```
package forum14651918;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlType(namespace="http://www.mypage.com/schemas/pdi")
public class Product {

    private int number;

}
```

**Instance (forum14651918/Instance.java)**

You can override the namespace for the `Instance` class using the `@XmlType` annotation.

```
package forum14651918;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(namespace="http://www.mypage.com/schemas/ib")
public class Instance {

    private String serial;

}
```

**Demo (forum14651918/Demo.java)**

Below is some code you can run to prove that everything works.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Envelope.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum14651918/input.xml");
        Envelope envelope = (Envelope) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(envelope, System.out);
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/11/jaxb-and-namespace-prefixes.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: And would I have to add the XmlRootElement and XmlElement annotations or not?

Comment: @Nacho321 - All you need is the metadata I have in the answer.

Comment: For some reason, I can access the first level of the xml. For example, Envelope has a date attribute which I can access with no issues. But I when I try to access the product or the instance levels, I get an internal server error.

Comment: @Nacho - Have you tried running this standalone?  I've added an example of this to my answer (see `Demo` class).

Comment: Found the error. You were right all along. Turns out that there was an issue with the server. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `name="pdi:number", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/pdi"` with `name="number", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/pdi"`. Prefix is not needed.

What is more looking at the XML it seems  that namespace for both `Product` and `Instance` is `http://www.mypage.com/schemas/envelope`.

You should not need `@XmlRootElement` annotation for `Product` class. It is not a root element and is already configured on `getProduct()`.

Full configuration that should be OK is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name ="Envelope", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/envelope")
public class Envelope {


   @XmlElement(name="Product", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/envelope")
   public Product getProduct(){...}

   @XmlElement(name="Instance", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/envelope")
   public Instance getInstance(){...}

}
public class Product {

    @XmlElement(name="number", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/pdi")
    public int getNumber(){...}
}

public class Instance {

    @XmlElement(name="serial", namespace = "http://www.mypage.com/schemas/ib")
    public String getSerial(){...}
}
```

Comment: I get a request error. Any other ideas? I was maybe thinking that the namespaces where wrong or something, cuz I've never worked with more than one namespace before.

Comment: Weird... Now I'm getting an internal server error. Your logic does seem to be right... I'm sure it's something incredibly stupid that I'm overlooking. XD

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda - FYI, the metadata can be simplified by leveraging the `@XmlSchema` annotation:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14652368/383861