# JAXB unmarshalling issues when elements have namespaces

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, unmarshalling

This code only works if I remove "bpmn:" from all the elements inside the XML file, otherwise it throws the following exception:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected Element (URI:"http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL", local:"definitions"). Expected elements are <{}definitions> .

Im trying to make it work without modifying the XML file. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn:definitions xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="Definitions_13d3a6z" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="4.1.1">
  <bpmn:process id="Process_1tovjba" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_06i118e</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:startEvent>
    <bpmn:task id="Activity_1d3friu" name="Task 1">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_06i118e</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_0linmbs</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:task>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_06i118e" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="Activity_1d3friu" />
    <bpmn:task id="Activity_1e17g78" name="Task 2">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_0linmbs</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_0yu7ggy</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:task>
    <bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent id="Event_1tlw9ds">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_0yu7ggy</bpmn:incoming>
    </bpmn:intermediateThrowEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_0yu7ggy" sourceRef="Activity_1e17g78" targetRef="Event_1tlw9ds" />
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_0linmbs" sourceRef="Activity_1d3friu" targetRef="Activity_1e17g78" />
  </bpmn:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="Process_1tovjba">
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_06i118e_di" bpmnElement="Flow_06i118e">
        <di:waypoint x="215" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="360" y="117" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_0yu7ggy_di" bpmnElement="Flow_0yu7ggy">
        <di:waypoint x="840" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="931" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="931" y="190" />
        <di:waypoint x="1022" y="190" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_0linmbs_di" bpmnElement="Flow_0linmbs">
        <di:waypoint x="460" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="600" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="600" y="90" />
        <di:waypoint x="740" y="90" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_2" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds x="179" y="99" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_1d3friu_di" bpmnElement="Activity_1d3friu">
        <dc:Bounds x="360" y="77" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_1e17g78_di" bpmnElement="Activity_1e17g78">
        <dc:Bounds x="740" y="77" width="100" height="80" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_1tlw9ds_di" bpmnElement="Event_1tlw9ds">
        <dc:Bounds x="1022" y="172" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Definitions {

 private String id;
 private Process process;



    public Definitions(){};
    public Definitions(String id, Process process){
        this.id = id;
        this.process = process;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = "bpmn",name = "process")
    public Process getProcess() {
        return process;
    }

    public void setProcess(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
    }
}
```

```
public class XMLToObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            File file = new File("process.bpmn");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Definitions.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            Definitions definitions= (Definitions) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(definitions.getId());

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set the qualifier flag.  elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579814/how-do-i-set-the-elementformdefault-of-an-element-in-jaxb-on-a-single-class-basi

Comment: I tried all of the recommended solutions provided on the question. Unfortunately none of these solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the XML namespace **URIs** in your
`@XmlRootelement` and `@XmlElement` annotations,
not the XML namespace **prefixes** (`"bpmn"` or `"bpmndi"`).

So then your `Definitions` class would look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL")
public class Definitions {

    private String id;
    private Process process;
    private BPMNDiagram bpmnDiagram;

    public Definitions(){};
    public Definitions(String id, Process process, BPMNDiagram bpmnDiagram){
        this.id = id;
        this.process = process;
        this.bpmnDiagram = bpmnDiagram;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL", name = "process")
    public Process getProcess() {
        return process;
    }

    public void setProcess(Process process) {
        this.process = process;
    }

    @XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI", name = "BPMNDiagram")
    public BPMNDiagram getBpmnDiagram() {
        return bpmnDiagram;
    }

    public void setBpmnDiagram(BPMNDiagram bpmnDiagram) {
        this.bpmnDiagram = bpmnDiagram;
    }   
}
```

In a similar way you need to modify the `@XmlElement` annotations in your
other classes (`Process`, `BPMNDiagram`, ...).